# What does this line regarding COVID-19 laden food industry mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

[**This article**](https://www.yahoo.com/finance/news/why-franchises-are-faring-as-badly-as-small-restaurants-amid-delta-variant-surge-160127931.html) has this line,

> “A franchisee of a restaurant model invests everything, just like an independent operator. They gamble on everything,” Gagnon explained to Yahoo Finance.

> “Now they have a name on the door and **they have a system that they can pass questions, and ask for help and assistance,**” she said.

Would the bold line try to mean that the franchisee of the brand food business obtained the system regarding questioning (to potential customers) about COVID-19 and in case they found the affected, they have a certain procedure to ask somewhere what to do with them and other assistance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence is a direct quote from spoken English, so the grammar isn't very careful or formal.

Firstly, the "now" at the beginning of the sentence is probably just being used as a conversational filler, and doesn't refer to a particular point in time. The rest of the sentence is just stating some general facts about franchisees:

- "they have a name on the door" (the name of the brand they're a franchise of, like "McDonald's")
- "they have a system that they can ..." (this might better be phrased "they have a system *where* they can...")

  - "... pass questions"
  - "... ask for help and assistance"

So a possible paraphrase would be:

> Franchisees get to use the brand, and can contact the owner of that brand or ask them for help

The sentence actually continues in the next paragraph, starting "but...", so these facts are being laid out to set up the next point the speaker wants to make.

Comment: Can I ask what "pass question" would mean? "pass(hand out=ask the franchise) the question"? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, to "pass a question to somebody" is to send them a message containing that question. You might have to pass it to someone, who *passes it on* to someone else who can answer.

Comment: Thinking about it, it may also be trying to imply that is a customer asks the franchisee a question, and they don't know the answer, the franchisee can pass that question to the brand owner.

Comment: I'm not sure about "now" being conversational filler; rather, I think it's specifying the "now" in which the franchise owner is actually a franchisee - "before", they weren't, so they didn't have "a name on the door" or "a system they can...". But, now that they're a franchisee, they do. That is, it's contrasting the current state with a past (or even alternate present) state in which the franchise owner isn't (yet) a franchisee. The construction can also refer to an alternate future ("You've got a stand-alone restaurant, but become a franchisee and now you've got a system...").

Comment: @Kentaro: even if the interview deals with Covid, this line has nothing to do with it. It simply says that, unlike an independent restaurant that can rely on nobody else but themselves, a franchisee is part of a bigger chain and they can ask that chain (with supposedly much more experience than themselves) for help and assistance (in matters of Covid or anything else).

Comment: @Gábor I know. I just inserted the line only because I wasn't able to ask "Waht does line mean"....^^.